# Allow only one file of directory in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

I want to allow only one file of directory `/minsc`, but I would like to disallow the rest of the directory.

Now in the robots.txt is this:

```
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 10
# Directories
Disallow: /minsc/
```

The file that I want to allow is `/minsc/menu-leaf.png`

I'm afraid to do damage, so I dont'know if I must to use:

**A)**

```
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 10
# Directories
Disallow: /minsc/
Allow: /minsc/menu-leaf.png
```

or

**B)**

```
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 10
# Directories
Disallow: /minsc/*    //added "*" -------------------------------
Allow: /minsc/menu-leaf.png
```

?

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: Don't forget that the robot file is not any kind of security. It's only ever a "suggestion". So I don't think you can do any real damage here anyway. If do you get it wrong, the worst that can happen is that a search engine will no longer index your image file. The robot file *will not* prevent anyone from directly accessing the file, or any other files in that folder, nor will it stop your scripts from working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the robots.txt website](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html):

> **To exclude all files except one**
>
> This is currently a bit awkward, as there is no "Allow" field. The
>   easy way is to put all files to be disallowed into a separate
>   directory, say "stuff", and leave the one file in the level above this
>   directory:
>
> > User-agent: *
> >
> > Disallow: /~joe/stuff/
>
> Alternatively you can explicitly disallow all disallowed pages:
>
> > User-agent: *
> >
> > Disallow: /~joe/junk.html
> >
> > Disallow: /~joe/foo.html
> >
> > Disallow: /~joe/bar.html

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard), if you are going to use the Allow directive, it should go before the Disallow for maximum compatability:

```
Allow: /directory1/myfile.html
Disallow: /directory1/
```

Furthermore, you should put Crawl-delay last, according to [Yandex](https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.xml):

> To maintain compatibility with robots that may deviate from the
>   standard when processing robots.txt, the Crawl-delay directive needs
>   to be added to the group that starts with the User-Agent record right
>   after the Disallow and Allow directives).

So, in the end, your robots.txt file should look like this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /minsc/menu-leaf.png
Disallow: /minsc/
Crawl-delay: 10
```

Comment: so the option (A) of my post but for maximum compayability is better to put "allow" before the disallow. Ok? :)

Comment: @user3162975 I just edited my answer. Look at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Robots.txt is sort of an 'informal' standard that can be interpreted differently. The only interesting 'standard' is really how the major players are interpreting it.

I found this source saying that globbing ('*'-style wildcards) are not supported:

> Note also that globbing and regular expression are not supported in either the User-agent or Disallow lines. The '*' in the User-agent field is a special value meaning "any robot". Specifically, you cannot have lines like "User-agent: *bot*", "Disallow: /tmp/*" or "Disallow: *.gif".

http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

So according to this source you should stick with your alternative (A).

Comment: so with (A) that file is allow while all the rest of directory is disallow...yes ? i'm afraid to do damage..

Comment: @user3162975 That's how I read it but I'm not an expert in this area --- no guarantees. There is no authoritative standard on this; what you can do is read many different sources and form an opinion.

Comment: hmmm you're right :( meanwhile someone else write, I try to understand more.... thanks a lot! :)